# editable-text onbeforesave does not work

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have this html fragment in my application:

```
<span editable-text="vm.foundedUser.username" onbeforesave="vm.checkUsername($data)" onaftersave="vm.updateUser()">
    {{vm.foundedUser.username || '--'}}
</span>
```

and the checkUsername function looks like this:

```
function checkUsername(username) {
        if(typeof username == 'undefined' || username.length < 5) {
            return false;
        }
        validateService.checkUniqueUsername(username).success(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }).error(function(e){
              console.log('error in management.controller.js#checkUsername');
        });
    }
```

If username is to short thaan the function checkUsername works fine but if username is not unique than this function does not work for any reason - I can save a nonunique username. 
Does anyone know why onbeforesave does not return false for nonunique username?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the `validateService.checkUniqueUsername()` method, but I suspect the reason you are not getting a `false` return value is that `response.data` is used with `.then()` and you are using the deprecated `.success()` and `.error()` promise resolution methods. Try changing your call to this:

```
validateService.checkUniqueUsername(username)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        console.log('error in management.controller.js#checkUsername');
    });
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with the deprecated methods (*not recommended*) you can do this:

```
validateService.checkUniqueUsername(username).success(function(response) {
    return response; <-- note no .data here
}).error(function(e){
    console.log('error in management.controller.js#checkUsername');
});
```